# How to store the number of times a recursion method calls itself by use of binary tree

Tags: java, recursion, binary-tree

I couldn't figure out how to store the number of times a recursive method calls itself.  If any one could point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it! Below is my code in it i have a comment on where I think I am going wrong.

```
package module8_auriemma_assignment;
import java.util.*;

public class fibonacciTree{

Node root;

public void addNode(int key, int num) {
    Node newNode = new Node(key, num);

    if (root == null) {
        root = newNode;
    } 
            else {
        Node focusNode = root;
        Node parent;
        while (true) {
            parent = focusNode;
            if (key < focusNode.key) {
                focusNode = focusNode.leftChild;
                if (focusNode == null) {
                    parent.leftChild = newNode;
                    return;
                }
            } 
                            else 
                            { 
                focusNode = focusNode.rightChild;           
                if (focusNode == null) {
                    // then place the new node on the right of it
                    parent.rightChild = newNode;
                    return; // All Done
                }

            }

        }
    }

}



 public static void main(String[] args) {



    fibonacciTree theTree = new fibonacciTree();

    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter an index");
        System.out.println("I will compute your index's Fibonacci numbers.");
        System.out.println("I will compute numbers that do not exceed a billion");

        int number;

        int key;
        key = 0;

        for(number = input.nextInt(); number < 1000000; number++){


            System.out.println(fibonacci(number));                         
            theTree.addNode(key, number);

            /*
            I am not sure if I should be adding a new node everytime the
            loop happens in the main class OR if I should be having it store
            a node inside of the fibonacci method itself
            */

            number++;
            key++;

            } 

                    }

public static long fibonacci(int i)
{

            if (i == 0) return 0;
    if (i <= 2) return 1;

    long fibTerm = fibonacci(i - 1) + fibonacci(i - 2);

    if(fibTerm > 1000000000){
            System.out.println("Number  too large");

                System.exit(0);
            }
            else{
                return fibTerm;

            }
                return fibTerm;
}
}
```

.

```
package module8_auriemma_assignment;
class Node {
int key;
int num;

Node leftChild;
Node rightChild;

Node(int key, int num) {

    this.key = key;
    this.num = num;

}


    @Override
public String toString() {

    return num + " has the key " + key;



}

}
```

Comment: Hint: you want us to spent our time to help you. So you please spend the few minutes it would take to properly format your input code! There is even a nice "preview" function available. Seriously: I completely lost interest in answering your question when I figured that you just dumped such a mess on us. Then you want to study java coding style guides. Class names start UpperCase. Always.

Answer (score 0):

`fibonacci(int i)` keeps calling itself until it is reduced to a series of 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+...

The solution is also the number of times the method is called. If you want to know how many times it was called, look at the return value.